# Accessing elements of a class with strings

Tags: python

I was working on a problem earlier where I wanted to loop over the elements of a class but I didn't want to use

```
for attr, value in o.__dict__.iteritems()
```

since that would only return the elements of that object. I have two objects`A and B` and I want to use the `attr` variable so I can compare `A and B` but I couldn't find any way to do that. I know there is `eval()` but that wouldn't work. Here's an example of what I am trying to accomplish

```
class foo():
    def __init__(self,i=None, j=None):
        self.i = i
        self.j = j

A = foo(5)
B = foo(None, 2)

#If I have the string "i" I want to be able to access attribute i
list_of_attr = [k for k in dir(B) if not k.startswith('__')]

#list_of_attr = ['i','j']
for k in list_of_attr:
   print A.k

#expected output
5
None
```

instead it throws the error `AttributeError: foo instance has no attribute 'k'`

I was thinking A.eval(k) might work but it tries evaluate `eval()` as an attribute

Is there a way to do that or does Python not allow it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A.k` means trying to access property named `k` of `A`.

Use `getattr(A, k)`.

---

Using `eval`:

`eval('A.%s' % k)`

PS: Please try to refrain from using `eval` in your code.

Comment: I saw that while I was looking earlier but I misunderstood its use. Thank you

Comment: eval for such trivial task is a bad idea, getattr is sufficient.

Comment: Yes, i forgot to mention.